# What all core Node Js modules does Express Js built on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

What all core modules of Node.Js is used to built the Express Js Framework.
I know it have the 'http' and 'fs' modules, what else does Express Js have?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express check their repo

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=require+path%3Alib&type=Code search their repo

Comment: no it didn't help.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a simple search on the repository for `require`, and then manually checked the result. These are the core modules I came up with:

- assert
- events
- fs
- http
- https
- path
- url
- util

I have only checked the source code of Express itself, not its dependencies' source code.

Anyway, I hope this helps.

Just out of curiosity: What is this answer good for? Why do you want to know that?

Comment: its good to know the inner working. deep learning is what  I Seek. :D